# Set-ADComputer on non domain computer

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

I want to use PowerShell to add extensionattributes in AD from clean computer w/o ActiveDirectory module, so I need a .Net equivalent to `Set-ADComputer`.

Example:

```
Set-ADComputer -Identity My-Computer -Replace @{
    extensionAttribute1 = "MyAttribute"
}
```

Comment: [`Set-ADComputer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adcomputer) allows connecting with explicit credentials (`Set-ADComputer -Server -Credential`. You need to install the RSAT and activate the AD PowerShell module first, though.

Comment: If you want to avoid installing the RSAT you need to resort to the respective .Net methods/objects. Please do some research and try to come up with some code. SO is not a free script-writing service.

Comment: If you have the appropriate permissions, you could use "Enter-PSSession -ComputerName myComputer" to connect to a remote computer which either has RSAT installed or which is a Domain Controller and run your script/command there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$pc = "computername$"
$obj = ([adsisearcher]"samaccountname=$pc").FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry()
if($obj) {
    $obj.Put("extensionAttribute1", "myattribute")
    $obj.SetInfo()
}
```

another community helped